# changing value of `value` with variable for multiple`<input>' fields

Tags: jquery

Multiple input fields set value using **variable** called **multiplier**. Each input I added new custom attribute called **my_value** to calculated based on 3 drop-down and target table with corresponding values.
I can calculate the each input correctly and writes on SPAN.

However I have two issue or bug how can I resolve it?
1. I tried to set the input value with **variable multiplier** so when I select drop-down I see the value from corresponding table displays on **input value** it is shows on console log tried below code it does not set INPUT value only to test one Id it did not work, what is wrong?

```
$('#Cherry').val(multiplier);
```

or use for all inputs this below dont work, what is wrong?

```
$("input[type='number']") =multiplier;
```

I could not set inputs. please see below image for illustration.

2. Grand Total shows **"NaN"**
   if I set input value with default value and use below line grand total works fine (    `<input id="Cherry" name="Cherry" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="40"  readonly="true"/>`)

   result.text($(this).val() * multiplier);

If I remove all Value from input set custom attribute  my_value ="40" it calculates each input but Grand Total shows **NaN**

```
result.text($(this).attr("my_value") * multiplier);

<input id="Cherry" name="Cherry" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" my_value ="40" readonly="true"/>
```

**For Example or more detailed explanation for my look up table **
[image]
***Many thanks***

```js
function myCalculate(){
  var volume = $("#Volume").val();
  var productOrigin = $("#ProductOrigin").val();
  var geographicalLocation = $("#GeoLocation").val();
  
  if (volume === "" || productOrigin === "") {
  // alert("Please select the product origin and volume.");
  return;
 }
  
  var tableToUse = geographicalLocation === "" ? productOrigin : geographicalLocation;
  
  $("input[type='text']").each(function(i){
    
    // Current product ID, e.g. "Apple", "Apricot", etc.
   var currentProductId = $(this).attr('id');
    
    // Amount to multiply.
    var multiplier = $(`table#${tableToUse} tbody > tr[product='${currentProductId}'] > td[volume='${volume}']`).text();
    
    // A <span> element, to be populated with the calculated product volume.
 var result = $("<span name='result'>");

 // Calculate the figure and update the result element.
 result.text($(this).attr("my_value") * multiplier); 

 // Remove any previously added <span> result elements.
 $(this).next("span").remove();

 // Insert result after the current input field.
 $(this).after(result);
    
   
        // to calculate Grand total
        function getInputs(selector) {
          var inputs = 0;
          $(selector).each(function() {
            $(this).find("input").each(function() {
              sum += parseInt($(this).html());
               $('#').val(parseInt($(this).html()));
            var multiplier = $(`table#${tableToUse} tbody > tr[product='${currentProductId}'] > td[volume='${volume}']`).text();
              //  $('#GrandTotal').val(sum); // give the final sum from Log
            });
          });
          return sum;
        }
    
    // to calculate Grand total
        function getDivSum(selector) {
          var sum = 0;
          $(selector).each(function() {
            $(this).find("span").each(function() {
              sum += parseInt($(this).html());
               $('#GrandTotal').val(parseInt($(this).html()));
              //  $('#GrandTotal').val(sum); // give the final sum from Log
            });
          });
          return sum;
        }
    
    console.log(getDivSum("#sumDiv"))
    $("#GrandTotal").next().html(getDivSum("#sumDiv"))
    
        $(document).ready(function() {
          console.log(getDivSum("#sumDiv"));
        });

  }); 
  
}


$('.select').on('change', myCalculate);
$("input[type='text']").on('keyup', myCalculate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="ProductOrigin">Product Origin</label>
  <select class="element select medium" id="ProductOrigin" name="ProductOrigin">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
    <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
    <option value="China">China</option>
    <option value="India">India</option>
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <label class="description" for="GeoLocation">Geographical Location</label>
  <select class="element select medium" id="GeoLocation" name="GeoLocation">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="England">England</option>
    <option value="Scotland">Scotland</option>
    <option value="Wales">Wales</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Volume">Volume</label>
  <select class="element select medium" id="Volume" name="Volume">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="sumDiv">
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Apple">Apple</label>
  <input id="Apple" name="Apple" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" my_value ="10" readonly="true"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Apricot">Apricot</label>
  <input id="Apricot" name="Apricot" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" my_value ="20" readonly="true"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Banana">Banana</label>
  <input id="Banana" name="Banana" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" my_value ="20" readonly="true"/>
</div>

<div>
  <label class="description" for="GrandTotal">Grand Total</label>
  <input id="GrandTotal" name="GrandTotal" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" readonly="true"/>
</div>

</div>

<table id="Europe">
  <thead>Europe</thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Europe</td>
    <th id=10>10</th>
    <th id=100>100</th>
    <th id=1000>1000</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr product='Apple'>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td volume='10'>0.1</td>
      <td volume='100'>0.5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Apricot'>
      <td>Apricot</td>
      <td volume='10'>0</td>
      <td volume='100'>0</td>
      <td volume='1000'>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr product='Banana'>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td volume='10'>0.1</td>
      <td volume='100'>0.5</td>
      <td volume='1000'>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

to test, please select **Product Origin: Europe**, **Geographical Location: blank**  and **any Volume from dropdown**

Comment: to test, please select Product Origin: Europe and Geographical Location: blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below line to replace the input:

```
  // Insert result after the current input field.
    $(this).after(result);
```

To calculate the total, I managed to fix it the issues, setting the value for each input was achieved by this line:

// Insert result after the current input field.
$(this).after(result);

and getting submit achieved by this line

```
 sum += +$(this).text();
 //console.log("Value sum "+sum);
 $('#GrandTotal').val(sum);
```